# Which of the following codes is the correct way of using Promises in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

So, I would consider this more of a discussion rather than a question. I was working with Promises and my code was fully functional and everything was working fine but then I came across another way of achieving the same result, but I feel that this way is not the best way of using Promises. So, I wanted to discuss how to effectively use Promises.

So, what I am trying to do is fetch the data of different pokemons using the `pokeapi` and then display the names and the types of the pokemons in the order which they appear. (**NOTE: It is important that the order doesn't break**).

I `fetch` this url first `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150`, then `.json()` the response and then this json contains an array `results` that contains urls for each pokemon in order. Now I use `Promise.all()` to fetch all these urls and then again `Promise.all()` for converting these responses into jsons. **Note: I use Promise.all() twice this is important because the second approach uses it only once which bothers me.**

> So, this is the code that I wrote

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const responseArr = [];
    json.results.forEach(el => {
      responseArr.push(fetch(el.url));
    });

    return Promise.all(responseArr);
  })
  .then(responses => {
    const jsonArr = [];
    responses.forEach(el => {
      jsonArr.push(el.json());
    });

    return Promise.all(jsonArr);
  })
  .then(jsons => {
    jsons.forEach((json, index) => {
      const pokemonName = json.name;
      const pokemonType = json.types[0].type.name;
      container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemonType} <br>`;
    });
  })
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

> And this is the second approach

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json(), e => {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  })
  .then(json => {
    Promise.all(json.results.map(el => fetch(el.url)))
      .then(arr => {
        arr.map(response => response.json())
          .forEach((result, index) => {
            result.then(el => {
              const pokemonName = el.name;
              const pokemontype = el.types[0].type.name;
              container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemontype} <br>`;
            })
          })
      }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
        throw e;
      });
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
    throw e;
  });
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

In the second solution, this portion bothers me.

```
arr.map(response => response.json())
          .forEach((result, index) => {
            result.then(el => {
              const pokemonName = el.name;
              const pokemontype = el.types[0].type.name;
              container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemontype} <br>`;
            })
          })
```

Because `response.json()` will also return promise so it should also be chained properly, here the one's whose `.json()` is fulfilled first will get added into the inner HTML first, so the order of listing the pokemons might get disturbed.

Also, I found something weird just now while writing this, if the api endpoint is changed to `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=15` i.e. requesting only for 15 pokemons, the order gets disturbed for the second approach everytime the code is executed but surprisingly it stays intact when requesting for 150 pokemons.

Comment: To me, everything you show is the old way of doing it. I use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) these days and avoid `then` completely.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "in the order which they appear. (NOTE: It is important that the order doesn't break)." ?  @LonnieBest - if there's even a question here, translating it into the more modern (but exactly equivalent) async/await syntax won't change the question, and might even obscure it.

Comment: "*so the order of listing the pokemons might get disturbed.*" - yes indeed. Do not use this approach.

Comment: @danh By order I mean the order in which it gets inserted into the DOM. `(1) Bulbasaur grass` should be before `(2) Ivysaur Grass`.

Comment: Okay, so you're okay fetching all of the returned pokemon urls with Promise.all(), it *does not* guarantee that those fetches will complete in any order, but it **does* guarantee that the resulting array order will match the order of the passed promises.

Comment: It looks to me that running results of your second approach for both 15 and 150 are out of order too. Maybe you should try running it for more times in order to reproduce the order disturbance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so the order of listing the pokemons might get disturbed.

Yes indeed. Do not use this approach if it is broken.

However, this doesn't mean that you need to use `Promise.all` twice. Instead of first waiting for all responses and then waiting for all response bodies, make a separate promise chain for each item in the array, and then only wait for all end results at once:

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const jsonPromises = json.results.map(el => {
      return fetch(el.url).then(response => response.json());
    });
    return Promise.all(jsonPromises);
  })
  .then(arr => {
    for (const [index, json] of arr.entries()) {
      const pokemonName = json.name;
      const pokemonType = json.types[0].type.name;
      container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemonType} <br>`;
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I recommend TTY112358's solution. But to answer your initial question, which was not about performance:

Promises were designed, among other things, so you could avoid the nesting in your second example. So yeah, the first version is more "correct" — or to be more precise, the second version is just as correct but it's ugly, written in what is considered a bad style.

BTW, your first example could be simplified by using `map`, like this, and you'll see that `async/await` isn't necessarily superior to a well-written chain of `then`s — it really depends on whether the logic is indeed a chain and whether you have ready-to-use functions that can be used in it:

```
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then({results} => Promise.all(results.map(el => fetch(el.url))))
  .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(el => el.json()))
  .then(jsons => {
    jsons.forEach((json, index) => {
      const pokemonName = json.name;
      const pokemonType = json.types[0].type.name;
      container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemonType} <br>`;
    });
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the url to 15, and run the second appraoch?

Comment: Well explained! Promise is designed for ridding 'callback hells' shown in Som's second approach, and 'async/await' is just something like syntax sugar to make code more readable (under most but not all circumstances).

Answer (score 1):

What about the following solution which prints pokemon as fast as possible and keeps the order at the same time.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

async function fetchPokemons(){
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150');
  const {results} = await response.json();
  const promises = results.map(async (result, index) => {
    const {url} = result;
    const pokemon = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    await Promise.all(promises.slice(0, index));
    const pokemonName = pokemon.name;
    const pokemontype = pokemon.types[0].type.name;
    container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemontype} <br>`;
    return;
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

fetchPokemons();
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: What does {results} mean? What does this curly braces signify?

Comment: This is object destructure. You can check https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/